# Find critical points for the Lotka-Volterra problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the critical points of the Lotka-Volterra problem:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{dt}\begin{vmatrix}
    u\\
    v
    \end{vmatrix}=
    \bf{F}(u,v)=\begin{vmatrix}
    3u-u^2-uv\\
    -v+uv
    \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

I tried first to solve each expression set equal to zero, and solve by substitution, but that gave me $u=1, v=0$. Since this is not correct, I tried the following:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d}{dt}\begin{vmatrix}
    3u-u^2-uv\\
    -v+uv
    \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
3-2u-v-udv\\
v+udv-dv
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

So I tried to solve

$$3-2u-v-udv=0$$
$$v+udv-dv=0$$

This gives:

$$udv=3-2u-v$$
$$udv=v+dv$$

So, that means we can substitute one into the other and get:

$$v+dv=3-2u-v$$

$$ dv=3-2u-2v$$

separating variables:

$$2v+ dv=3-2u$$

But from here I am stuck, Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to find the critical points of $F(u, v)$ by simultaneously solving $u' = v' = 0$.

We have

$$\begin{align} 3u-u^2-uv &= 0 \\ -v+uv &= 0 \end{align}$$

From the second equation

$$v(u -1) = 0 \implies v = 0 ~~\mbox{or}~~ u = 1$$

Substituting $v = 0$, into the first equation

$$3u - u^2 = u(3-u) = 0 \implies u = 0 ~~\mbox{or}~~ u= 3$$

Substituting $u = 1$, into the first equation

$$3 - 1 - v = 0 \implies v = 2$$

This gives three critical points

$$(u, v) = (0,0),(3, 0), (1,2)$$

**Update**

Next you could find the phase portrait and determine the stability using the eigenvalues of the critical points, unless they are the marginal ones.

A phase portrait shows the behavior of the critical points

[image]

The Jacobian is

$$J(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}
 -2 u-v+3 & -u \\
 v & u-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now you would find the eigenvalues at each of the critical points and those should match the phase portrait (two unstable and one stable) critical points.

Comment: Astonishing work Moo! Thanks!!

Comment: what is the classification of a critical point, if one has only ONE eigenvalue? I cannot find it anywhere. Only two eigenvalues. Is it a center?

Comment: I just saw, I calculated the last CP to give one single eigenvalue, 0.5. That wold give a center right? But it looks like a source.

Comment: Though you are right, I have: $$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{vmatrix}
    -1-\lambda & -1\\
    2& -\lambda
    \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

Comment: You are right! Sorry, miscalculated at Wolfram

Comment: That is  spiral with complex eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes - correct, see Section 10.4.5 at https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Chemical_Process_Dynamics_and_Controls_(Woolf)/10%3A_Dynamical_Systems_Analysis/10.04%3A_Using_eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_to_find_stability_and_solve_ODEs#:~:text=If%20the%20two%20repeated%20eigenvalues,point%20is%20a%20stable%20sink.